# Detect expired cookie and logout user

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

After log in, I have a cookie [image]. I am wondering, if it's possible for my app to detect if cookie has expired, and then force logout action? Or just force router push to /login

Does it needs to be done with axios interceptors response or in router guard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options that I know of.

**Option 1** (recommended)

Setup an axios interceptor on the response object and listen to the returned responses from the server. Particularly error codes. If the server sends a 401 you can logout the user or request for a new access token to keep user logged in. You can use this [npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-auth-refresh) to implement the axios interceptors. With the library you can mention the error codes you want to listen to. So, I usually send a 498 error code from the server for all cases that involve expired access tokens, so its easier for me distinguish between expired and unauthorized tokens.

**Option 2** (not recommended)

You can use this [npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode) to decode the JWT on the frontend and extract the expiry time from the token. Create a `setInterval()` function that regularly checks if the current time is greater or equal to the expiry time. If it is true logout user or request a new token.

Go with option 1 because authenticating a token or its expiry time is the job of the auth server and nobody else. The front-end shouldn't be in charge of deciding whether the token is valid or not. Plus, you don't have to work with `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`, because you'll have to take into account additional edge cases as well.

Comment: Why does my server returns `500` code instead `401`?

Comment: 500 is usually an internal server error. It can be for a lot of reasons. I suggest you create a new question to tackle that problem and make sure you share the error message along with the stack trace in your question.